# Using ArcGIS Field Calculator to create classes in new field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I first classified `firstCol` into groups and then I want to give the groups with different weighted values in another field, `SecondCol`. I will need to give different weighted values very often. I find it very time-consuming whenever I modify the weighted values in my script.

---

My column looks like this:

[image]

I use the following script to calculate the `SecondCol`:

```py
def TextValue(gridcode):
if gridcode <= 5:
    return 1
elif  5 < gridcode <= 15:
    return 2
elif  15 < gridcode <= 30:
    return 3
elif  30 < gridcode <= 40:
    return 4
elif  40 < gridcode <= 55:
    return 5
elif  55 < gridcode <= 100:
    return 6
elif  100 < gridcode :
    return 7
else:
    return "N/A"

TextValue( !firstCol! )
```

As you can see, I give the weighted value as below:

```py
(weighted values  ,  group).

1   =   group "firstCol  < 5"    
2   =   group "firstCol = 5 - 15"    
3   =   group "firstCol = 15 - 30"    
4   =   group "firstCol = 30 - 40" 
5   =   group "firstCol = 40 - 55"    
6   =   group "firstCol = 55 - 100"    
7   =   group "firstCol > 100"
```

---

I wonder if there is a better way to give new weighted values more efficiently. Like, just give a new column in the beginning of the script.

```py
61  =   group "firstCol  < 5"   
8   =   group "firstCol = 5 - 15"    
88  =   group "firstCol = 15 - 30"    
70  =   group "firstCol = 30 - 40"   
52  =   group "firstCol = 40 - 55"    
2   =   group "firstCol = 55 - 100"    
6   =   group "firstCol > 100"

def TextValue( gridcode):
if ...
...
else...

TextValue( !firstCol! )
```

Then, the script will use the new values, instead of me modifying it in the `TextValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need **MORE** control over the class/label name and interval **WISELY**  and want to use **ANY** type of equality check then a way is to use `dictionary`  that keeps order (i.e. `OrderedDict`) and `eval` check as below where you have good command in interval for class and label for a class.To edit **class** (i.e. `1,2,3` etc.) and **interval** (i.e. `'0<x<=5','5<x<=15','15<x<=30'` etc.) just edit

```
{1:'0<x<=5',2:'5<x<=15',:'15<x<=30',4:'30<x<=40',5:'40<x<=55',6:'55<x<=100',7:'100<x'}`
```

**See full implementation**

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
#Setup class name and interal definition for that class/label- you can change here as you want
lookup_table = OrderedDict({1:'0<x<=5', 2:'5<x<=15', 3:'15<x<=30',4:'30<x<=40',5:'40<x<=55',6:'55<x<=100',7:'100<x'})
#Define function that determines the class/label
def labeller(val):
  try:
    #find the True value for check that is used to determine class/label
    chks = [eval(v.replace('x',str(val))) for v in lookup_table.values()]#It is just a true/false list
    if True in chks and chks.count(True)==1:
      v= lookup_table[chks.index(True)+1]
      for ky,vl in lookup_table.iteritems():
        if vl == v:
          return str(ky)
  except:
    return 'N/A'
```

And run it-

```py
labeller(!firstCol!)
```

**N.B. I used `OrderedDict` for performance - you can use normal dictionary too.**

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:

```py
def Get_Class(depth):
 breaks=[0.5,1,2,3,5,10,100000]
 n=len(breaks)
 for i in range(n):
  if  breaks[i] >= depth:
   m=i+1; break
 return m

'===============================================

Get_Class( !AREA_HA! )
```

It will look cooler with enumerate though

Comment: Thanks, FelixIP! Your script works for sequence number very well. But what if I need to give non-sequence numbers? like change 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 into 12, 42, 11, 68, 54, 10?

Comment: Create second list and pick from it using [m]

Comment: Your comment and question are mismatch. One thing reclass using interval (Question) and very different is reclass using lookup (Comment)

Comment: Sorry for my misleading description. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ FelixIP Does `breaks[i] >= depth:` considers the first label(i.e. 5) since then it needs <5?

Comment: 1st we need to understand where 15,30 etc go. My expression treats breaks as less or equal

Comment: @ FelixIP Exactly- it can only evaluate either <= or => - but first class may expects equality check that is different from the rest of the check.