# Reclass or other if/then logic expression in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to reclass values in field calculator using Python (recreating something I did successfully last month and am failing now). I've reviewed many questions and answers on this site with no success.

---

I've followed multiple examples from ArcGIS help and on this site, and regardless of how I change my statements, the calculator returns only one answer for all records. I added a picture as an example.

I wrote the following pre-logic script code, but the calculator returns "1" for all data.
I have a field (Percent) of percentages and I'd like to bin them into 5 groups in the cate field:
greater than or equal to 80; greater than or equal to 60 and less than 80; greater than or equal to 40 and less than 60; greater than or equal to 20 and less than 40; greater than or equal to 0 and less than 20.

I have no python experience and am just trying to replicate examples from GIS help and answers to similar questions on this site.

```
def Reclass(Percent):
  if Percent >= 80:
    return 5
  elif Percent >= 60 and Percent < 80: 
    return 4
  elif Percent >= 40 and Percent < 60:
    return 3
  elif Percent >= 20 and Percent < 40:
    return 2
  elif Percent >= 0 and Percent < 20:
    return 1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: See the [example here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm), scroll to _Calculate fields using logic with Python_. This may not be the issue but you should put your conditionals in parenthesis, e.g `(Percent >= 60 and Percent < 80)`. Additionally what are some of the values in the field _Cate_? It could be that in fact everything is greater than 0 and less than 20, so returning 1 for everything is valid.

Comment: Thanks. The values range from 0 to 100. I tried the parenthesis, with no effect. I based my original statement on the example you provided and am not able to get the calculation to work.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177652/calculate-field-more-wisely

Comment: Thanks. The expression is still not working - it only returns the answer for the first logic statement (if I say "return 1" if Percent <= 20 in the first statement, it returns "1" for all 1200 records regardless of the actual number in the Percent field - so 80 returns as "1" as well ). Maybe an issue with my data? It is strange because I was able to make it work before with this same data.

Comment: Does the third picture have any direct relevance to what *you* have tried and where *you* are stuck?  If not, then I think you should delete it and provide details of the data types for any fields that *you* are trying to use in *your* field calculation.

Comment: @Kristin, did you ever get this to processing. I am having the same issue, trying to perform a logical reclass on a dataset that I have performed this on before, and all I get are '1's' in the output.?