# How to label lines and rows of points?

Tags: python, arcmap, modelbuilder, labeling

How to labeling this rows and column of points so we could identified each point belong to what rows or what column depending on the polygon or starting point without depending by X or Y coordinate because the variations of points sometimes doesn't straight but askew by some degree?

I'am using arcmap btw, so arcpy or model builder or just simply labeling proccess would be big help.

[image]

sample created manually.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question. Are you trying to use ArcPy, ModelBuilder, Python libraries other than ArcPy or something else to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This a workflow that seems to work. Assign unique names to your points, you'll need it later to transfer nCol and nRow from BACKUP layer:

```
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management("BACKUP", "/RECTANGLE.shp", "RECTANGLE_BY_AREA")
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management("BACKUP", "./CONVEX.shp", "CONVEX_HULL")
```

[image]

Use spatial adjustment and 4 pairs of polygon corners to squeeze BACKUP into rectangle.

After that:

```
arcpy.SplitLine_management("RECTANGLE", "./splits.shp")
```

Select leftmost line in splits and calculate distance to it from points. Transformed points below are shown using graduated color symbols based on near distance:

[image]

I labelled them by values in a new integer field populated using technique described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177652/calculate-field-more-wisely).

I hope the remaining part, - computing rows (?) is clear. After completion use join by attribute (point unique names) to transfer row and column number back to original oblique points.