# Classifying fields and getting statistics in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification, statistics, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I have a table with country data. I am interested in Asia only, so I created a new layer (and shapefile). Several countries have missing data, which was filled with the same value (-50). One of the fields is Life Expectancy and another is Access to Drinking Water(population percent). I classified the Life Expectancy field (about 30 unique values) into 5 classes (in the symbology tab). I don't know how to group the countries by class (in the attribute table) so I can calculate various stats by class.

For example, What is the mean Access to Drinking Water, by Life Expectancy class?

Comment: Have you looked at the Summary Statistics tool?

Comment: I have looked but found nothing on the classification part.

Comment: You said that you already have the five class values from your classification for symbology so you could use the Field Calculator to update a field you then use to group by in Summary Statistics.

Comment: Create classes in new field https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177652/calculate-field-more-wisely?r=SearchResults and use summary statistics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ratio between the two columns, use the field calculator and divide Access to drinking water by Life expectancy and save the results in a new field.

If you want to compare the two fields go to "view -> graphs -> create Graph" and you can see the results on a line graph or a scatter plot.

you also can use the 3-dimensional graphs with 3 fields of Access to water, Life expectancy, and state names.

If you want to represent the data as classes in your map, use symbology -> [multiple attributes](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010616).