# Using Python Parser in field calculator to update column from another column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.8

I am an experienced ArcMap user who is fairly new to Python. I am having trouble getting the script to look for a list of values and assign a new label in a new column. The script runs without errors but it does not fill in the new column.

Do the two columns need to be the same type?

I have provided the code that I use in the code block of the field calculator. In the other half of the field calculator I have

```
def reclass(Landing_Factor):
    if Landing_Factor >=1.0 and Landing_Factor <=1.99:
      return "A"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 2 and Landing_Factor <=2.99:
      return "B"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 3 and Landing_Factor <=3.99:
      return "C"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 4 and Landing_Factor <=4.99:
      return "D"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 5 and Landing_Factor <=5.99:
      return "E"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 6 and Landing_Factor <=6.99:
      return "F"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 7 and Landing_Factor <=7.99:
      return "G"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 8 and Landing_Factor <=8.99:
      return "H"
    elif Landing_Factor >= 9 and Landing_Factor <=9.99:
      return "I"    
    else:
      return "N/A"


BENCH_1 = TextValue( !BENCH_1! )
```

Comment: The function is named `reclass`. Where is `TextValue` defined? Note that your comparison operators leave room for 7.99000000001 to be encoded 'N/A' -- it is much safer to use '>=' and `<` together to prevent floating-point representation artifacts.

Comment: Was at the top of the script and i have placed it. That was an error on my part. I keep in mind using '>=' and < for the furture.

Comment: `BENCH_1 = TextValue( !BENCH_1! )` doesn't make much sense in this context.  If you want to calculate `bench_2 = reclass( !BENCH_1!)`, that would make sense (where Bench_2 is a Text field of at least width 3).  Note that, since you use early `return` directives, there is no difference between `elif` and `if` inside the function.

Comment: Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177652/using-arcgis-field-calculator-to-create-classes-in-new-field/177654#177654  it requires very little modification to achieve what you are after.